# golang FileHeader.Open() return error no such file or directory

Tags: go, file-header

When I am trying to test my upload api, I faced a problem with FileHeader.Open(). I want to mock FileHeader like this:

```
header := make(map[string][]string)

header["Content-Disposition"] = []string{` form-data; name="file"; filename="karthus.jpg"`}

header["Content-Type"] = []string{"image/jpeg"}
FileHeader := &multipart.FileHeader{

    Filename: "karthus.jpg",

    Header: header,

    Size: 1289231,
}
```

and when I call method `FileHeader.Open()`, I receive an error message `open: no such file or directory`. My file is in folder that I call `FileHeader.Open()`. Please explain for me. Thanks!

Comment: have you check the [FileHeader Struct](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#FileHeader)?

Comment: The [content and tmpfile fields](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/df2999ef43ea49ce1578137017949c0ee660608a/src/mime/multipart/formdata.go#L144-L145) are not set. The [ReadForm](https://godoc.org/mime/multipart#Reader.ReadForm) method is the only way to get a functioning FileHeader.

Comment: Thank ManjeetThakur and Cerise. Cerise is right.